# Giving cards away in Catan

Tags: catan

I’m playing Catan and my brother-in-law has 9 points with the longest road. I was sitting at 7 points and another player had a pretty long road with only 5 points.

So I gave that other player brick and wood so they could take the longest road. I ended up winning the game, and that was probably the only way I could have won.

Would that be illegal if I didn’t accept anything for the brick and wood? Would it be illegal if I accepted one sheep for say, two brick and two wood? I only did the trades on my turn.

Comment: Not a dup. The linked Question is about a very specific and different scenario. The Answer to the linked Question only answers half of this Question.

Comment: The linked question asks if a move that's legal in the rules should be allowed. This has nothing to do with this question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @ikegami - Completely a dup. The motivation here might be different, but both parts of Rick's question are answered by the various answers on the linked question.

Comment: @Ikegami Agree with AndyT. This is enough of a dupe to leave closed, at the very least the answer is exactly the same. The rules do not take into account motivation for trading for nothing, they simply state "You may not give away cards."

Comment: @AndyT, That's not true at all. "Would it be illegal if I accepted one sheep for say, two brick and two wood? " is not  answered anywhere in the answers to the other question. Furthermore, it's baffling to me that you think it's ok to direct people to people wondering about the trading rules to that very complicated Q&A. That's not the spirit of the site at all.

Comment: @Andrew, That's not true at all. "Would it be illegal if I accepted one sheep for say, two brick and two wood? " is not  answered anywhere in the answers to the other question. Furthermore, it's baffling to me that you think it's ok to direct people to people wondering about the trading rules to that very complicated Q&A. That's not the spirit of the site at all.

Comment: @ikegami - My apologies. You are correct, the other question does not cover disproportionate trades. I'm still happy with this being closed as a dup, as that side question isn't the main question being asked here. If a main question is acceptable, then a side question can get away with being in it. If the main question is answered elsewhere, then the side question should be a seperate, new question.

Comment: @ikegami Fair enough, you are correct that part is not covered, voting to reopen.

Comment: "Furthermore, it's baffling to me that you think it's ok to direct people to people wondering about the trading rules to that very complicated Q&A." - what? The other question has the OP asking about a slightly tortuous workaround, but the two upvoted answers give very clear rules quotes that cover Rick's main question.

Comment: @AndyT, No, it's worse than a complicated question. It's also the fact that answers actually says "It's allowed", because "it" in that question is a sequence of trade that's leaves you with the same thing as which you started. Someone wondering how trades works shouldn't have to figure out that half of the answer should be ignored.

Answer (score 9):

Permitted:

- One can trade a number of cards for a different number of cards.
  ⇒ You could accept a sheep.

Forbidden:

- One can't trade for nothing.
  ⇒ You can't accept nothing.
- One can't trade for resources of the same type as those being traded away.
  ⇒ You can't accept any amount of brick or lumber.

The following are the rules concerning Domestic Trades:

> On your turn, you may trade resources with the other players (after rolling for resource production). You and the other players negotiate the terms of your trades—such as which cards will be exchanged. **You may trade as many times as you can, using single or multiple cards, but you may not give away cards (i.e., “trade” 0 cards for 1 or more cards).**
>
> Important: While it is your turn you must be a part of all trades, the other players may not trade amongst themselves.
>
> Example: It is Pete’s turn. He needs one brick to build a road. He has 2 lumber and 3 ore. Pete asks aloud, “Who will give me 1 brick for 1 ore?” Beth answers, “If you give me 3 ore, I’ll give you a brick.” Cooper interjects, “**I’ll give you 1 brick if you give me 1 lumber and 1 ore.**” Pete accepts Cooper's offer and trades a lumber and an ore for a brick. Note Beth may not trade with Cooper, since it is Pete’s turn.

The following are the rules concerning Trades:

> After you roll for resource production, you may trade with other players (domestic trade) or with the bank (maritime trade). If you decide not to trade during your turn, no one can trade. You may trade with another player between your turns, but only if it is his turn and he elects to trade with you. You cannot trade with the bank during another player’s turn. **You may not give away cards.** You may trade as long as you have Resource Cards. You may not trade Development Cards. **You may not trade like resources (e.g., 2 wool for 1 wool).**

Emphasis in both quotes is mine.