# Is a player locked in to a poorly worded trade offer?

Tags: catan

Is the following allowed?

Player A: holds up two woods and says "I will take any one resource for two woods"

Player B: Gives him a wood for his two woods.

Player A: tries to say he meant any resource besides wood since this trade is not allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving cards away in Catan](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44161/giving-cards-away-in-catan)

Comment: Not only is it illegal, but Player A could have just rejected the trade. Just because you offer a trade suggestion doesn't mean you have to ultimately make the trade.

Comment: I think there are 2 separate things going on in this scenario, and only 1 of them is covered by the linked duplicate.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate, the questioner doesn't appear to be attempting to give away resources.

Comment: @PatLudwig, the (only) answer to "Giving cards away..." states the rule that like-for-like trades are not allowed. But if that's not enough, there's also [Is it legal to trade 1 wood for 1 wood + 1 hay?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50275/is-it-legal-to-trade-1-wood-for-1-wood-1-hay)  (Both are marked as a duplicates of the very same question.)

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple issues with the way this played out.

First of all, trading 2 wood for 1 wood is not a legal trade, as outlined in [the rulebook](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf):

> You may **not** trade like resources (e.g., 2 wool for 1 wool).

But aside from that, simply stating "I will take any (1) resource for (2) woods" is not actually making a trade, it is simply proposing a general offer. Once players respond to that offer, there can be negotiation and then eventually an actual trade is made.

In this case, Player B doesn't just "give him 1 wood", rather player B would say "ok, how about 1 wood?" at which point Player A can say "no, what else you got?"

It is important to distinguish between "proposing a trade" and "making a trade". I can say "I will give a sheep for a wood", but if the only player willing to do it is someone who has 9 points so I don't want to trade with them, I don't have to trade with them. I can always just say "sorry, not trading with you". Making statements about what sort of trade you want is not a binding agreement; the actual agreement comes when 2 different players say "ok" to a specific set of resources exchanging with other resources.